# Simplify path settings in Inkscape

Tags: vector, inkscape, path

Using `Inkscape 0.92.4` (latest ATM), is there a way to tweak the settings of the *simplify path* tool?

I'm specifically talking about having some control on the number of nodes the path will have after simplifying as the tool uses too few nodes, resulting in very different path shape from original.

The *multiple quick taps* approach don't work because path is oversimplified with just one.
Also read about tweaking in `Edit > Preferences > Misc` (or a very similar route) but with `Inkscape 0.92.4` I can't find any option in there.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but: you can use path modifiers (or so) → simplify to experiment with the settings. Unfortunately you can't apply it to the actual path from there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want Edit / Preferences / Behaviour and you can set a number there. The lower the number, the less change when you try to simplify.

[image]